# Работа с файлами С++. 1)Выводит иероглифы

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, кириллица, fstream

Здравствуйте, я только учусь и ошибки могут быть очень глупыми. Хотел узнать

Как избавится от иероглифов в том случае если текст в файле на русском языке.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    int counter = -1;
    ifstream fd; 
    fd.open("strings.txt"); 
    char c;
    while (!fd.eof()) //цикл для того чтоб определить из скольки элеиентов должен быть массив
    {
        fd.get(c);
        counter++;
    }
    fd.close();
    fd.open("strings.txt");
    char* b = new char[counter+1];
    int j = 0;

    fd.get(b,counter+1);

    for(int i =0;i<counter;i++)//вывод
    {
        cout << b[i];
    }
    delete[]b;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Чтобы не пропускал пробелы, вместо `>>` используйте [`get()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get).

Comment: Ходят слухи что топ ребята читают файлы по байту...

Comment: Подсчет количества символов в файле циклом - бессмысленная идея. Гораздо эффективнее использовать seek. Но, раз уж c++ и stream, то лучше использовать istreambuf_iterator. Выглядит: std::copy(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{fin}, std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{}, std::back_inserter(str));

Comment: Обычный UTF-8 файл...

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch так вроде бэд бит генериться будет при попытке последнего инкремента итератора

Comment: @Maggot ну да... А в чем проблема?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch ну плохо это вроде как)))

Comment: @Maggot не объясните чем это плохо?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch не давайте представим,  что кто-то .exceptions(std::ifstream::badbit | std::ifstream::failbit); установил такую грязь. и не обложил все траем.... в итоге факап

Comment: @Maggot ничего не понял. Но давайте по порядку: при попытке инкремента последнего итератора - да, будет fail, но последний то итератор не инкрементится. Забыли как работает begin-end? Во-вторых поток будет установлен в eof (конец файла). В-третьих после считывания поток не используется и к нему нет обращений. Что обкладывать try-catch, что за грязь и какой факап я так и не понял.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch спасибо, я Вас понял)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос не давал мне покоя так как я помню что с ним сталкивался. В конце концов он плавал на поверхности. Создаем файл .txt -> открываем -> Сохранить как.
Внизу окна сохранения будет пункт Кодировка. Меняем на UTF-8, если стоит ANSII, или наоборот если иначе. Пробуем

Comment: Мир дому вашему, добрый человек!

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендую всегда использовать

```
SetConsoleCP(1251);
SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
```

вместо

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru")
```

должно работать (шрифт консоли - Lucida Console)

Comment: Шрифт программно менять? Если да, то как? Заранее спасибо

Comment: Если при использовании 
`SetConsoleCP(1251);SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);`
Вместо  `setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru")`, то тоже самое

Comment: @ElektroNIK не гарантирую пользу от это но клик правой кнопкой мыши по Шапке консоли -> свойства. Там разберетесь